# Pull information from a column to inside a for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have an Orders project where I want to implement label printing. each order must show the quantity of labels according to its quantity of objects. So far I have managed to show the quantity with a "for".

DB example:

```
+-------+-------------+-----+
| order | description | qty |
+-------+-------------+-----+
|   1   |   stickers  |  1  |
|   2   |   posters   |  2  |
|   2   |   tape      |  1  |
|   2   |  (no desc)  |  1  |
+-------+-------------+-----+
```

What I have so far:

```
Select SUM(qty) AS pieces FROM mytable WHERE order = '2'");
    $total=$row['pieces']; //this correspond to all items on the order.

for ($x = 1; $x <= $row_count; $x++){
  echo $order."<br>"; //order number
  echo $x."<br>"; //item
  echo $total."<br>"; //total items
}
```

Result:

```
           #order   #item   #total        #order   #item   #total
          +-------+-------+-------+      +-------+-------+-------+
posters   |   2   |   1   |   4   |      |   2   |   2   |   4   |
          +-------+--- ---+-------+      +-------+-------+-------+

        #order   #item   #total
       +-------+-------+-------+
tape   |   2   |   3   |   4   |
       +-------+-------+-------+

            #order   #item   #total
           +-------+-------+-------+
(no desc)  |   2   |   4   |   4   |
           +-------+-------+-------+
```

But I was unable to display the content of the 'description' column of each.

Desirable result:

```
         #order  #desc #item #total    #order  #desc #item #total
          +---+--------+----+----+      +---+--------+----+----+
posters   | 2 | posters|  1 |  4 |      | 2 | posters|  2 |  4 |
          +---+--------+----+----+      +---+--------+----+----+

      #order  #desc #item #total
       +---+--------+----+----+
tape   | 2 |  tape  |  3 |  4 |
       +---+--------+----+----+

          #order  #desc #item #total
           +---+---------+----+----+
(no desc)  | 2 |(no desc)|  4 |  4 |
           +---+---------+----+----+
```

Is there any chance of getting this result?
I'm using php and mysql.

Comment: `$row['qty']` should be `$row['pieces']`

Comment: I don't understand the question. The query doesn't get the description, how are you expecting to display it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry  I already corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the total query with a query of the table itself.

```
SELECT m.description, m.qty, t.total
FROM mytable AS m
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(qty) AS total
    FROM mytable
    WHERE order = 2
) AS t
WHERE order = 2
```

Then you can use nested loops:

```
$j = 1;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $row['description'];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $row['qty']; $i++, $j++) {
        echo "$order<br>{$row['description']}<br>$j<br>{$row['total']}<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, sorry about mistakes on my question. Thanks for your answer. Its great! I was able to get 'desc' where I want, but now I'm getting another result. I added it to my question.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I've updated the answer to show how to put the total in every item.

Comment: Wow excellent answer, its working, but after the 2nd array i++ value become "1" for the next 2 arrays (3 and 4). You know why? Sorry, as you can see I am learning.

Comment: I didn't see that the numbers incremented across different products. Just use a different variable for that.

Comment: Genius! Thanks a lot Barmar, this is the second time you save me.